# unable to get value of multiple radio button

Tags: javascript

I have many radio button in my form with different names group. I get the single radio group value but I want to get all group radio button values of the form.
here is my code where I am getting on feedback radio button value, not status. please help me. Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
     var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("feedback","status");
    for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x ++) {
      if (radioButtons[x].checked) {
       alert("You checked " + radioButtons[x].id);
       alert("Value is " + radioButtons[x].value);
     }
     }
  }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="feedback" id="outstanding" value="1" />Outstanding
<input type="radio" name="feedback" id="good" value="2" />Good
<input type="radio" name="feedback" id="accept" value="3" />Acceptable  
<input type="radio" name="status" id="done" value="1" />Done
<input type="radio" name="status" id="nothing" value="2" />Nothing
<input type="radio" name="status" id="work" value="3" />Work    
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right place-order-button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" >Finish</button>
</body>
</html>
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/nady/711evwd8/

Comment: `getElementsByName()` only accepts a single string argument

Comment: document.getElementsByName takes a single argument, so "status" is being ignored ... try querySelectorAll as an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can include Jquery here is the solution.

```js
function myFunction() {
 
     var radioButtons =["feedback","status"]; 
    for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x ++) {
      if ($('[name = "'+radioButtons[x]+'"]:checked')) {
       alert("You checked " + $('[name = "'+radioButtons[x]+'"]:checked').attr('id'));
       alert("Value is " + $('[name = "'+radioButtons[x]+'"]:checked').val());
     }
     }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="feedback" id="outstanding" value="1" />Outstanding
<input type="radio" name="feedback" id="good" value="2" />Good
<input type="radio" name="feedback" id="accept" value="3" />Acceptable  
<input type="radio" name="status" id="done" value="1" />Done
<input type="radio" name="status" id="nothing" value="2" />Nothing
<input type="radio" name="status" id="work" value="3" />Work    
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right place-order-button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" >Finish</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your feedle. If you wanted to print all of the radio buttons val's you just needed to get the alert out of the radioButtons[x].checked condition. Yet, if you wanted to print all of the values only if the condition was met you would've done something like this [feedle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/#&togetherjs=goqf5iDLlq)